# Unity WebGL Augmented Reality application not working on iOS, but works in Android

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, unity-webgl

As the title suggests, I have made an application using `Unity` and `WebGL` platform. 
 **The application runs on:**

- Windows (Firefox, Microsoft edge)
- Android (Chrome, Firefox)
- MacOS (Safari, Chrome)
- Unity (Edditor)

**The app does NOT run on:**

- iOS (Chrome, Safari, Firefox)

The application is using `WebCamTexture` to get the `camera` of the device. Wen running on all platforms except `iOS` the application asks for permition to share the device's `camera`. However on the `iOS` it just gives a `blue screen` and no other info.
The application does not crash, nor give any errors during launch on all platforms. Please tell me if I should share any relative code that might help. **How could I successfully run it on `iOS` using any browser?** Please share your experience and knowledge, any help is appreciated. 
**PS:** The plugin used for `WebGL` Augmented Reality is called *NyARToolkitUnity-5.0.8*. The `git` can be found [here](https://github.com/nyatla/NyARToolkitUnity/releases).

Another detail to mention: The application has been built and tested with both `Windows` (Unity) and `MacOS` (Unity). It's currently running on an `Asure` server.
The build can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2qgLqTMfCa2QzFndHlCZHRsRVk).
Thanks!

Comment: you'd better post an issue on the git project.

Comment: @Andromelus Good point, I will try to do that.

Comment: If you get the answer from the issue, could you please post a answer here with the link to the issue? Migth be usefull for other people

Comment: @Andromelus of course I will, although I doubt I would get a reply since the `git` hasn't been active since July 2016.

Comment: I'm working with `Vuforia` for 1.5 years now, they do not yet offer support for `WebGL`..

Comment: you can view your logs from your iOS browser using https://jsconsole.com/ set it up and post your log, most probably there is some exception during the gameplay.

Comment: @NikaKasradze Hey, thanks for the response, here is the errors in the log: `[Error] No Webcam.
 
(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/WebGL/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
    _JS_Log_Dump (blob:https://website.local/2cb69301-75ff-4292-9935-51798d75cfab:2:192474)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (events, line 0)`

Comment: wow, that was fast. I've never built WebGL for iOS before but, are you sure you have granted a permission for your app to use camera? Also, please add this log to your question. Maybe somebody else has seen it before

Comment: Yes, I am doing so with the following code `Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.WebCam);`

Comment: well I guest I can't help beyond this point

Comment: And on Android and Windows it asks me _Would you please share the device's camera_ even gives me the option of front and back

Comment: Well no problem, thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this?